# Goland debugger does step into functions

Tags: go, goland, delve

A couple of GoLand versions ago, the GoLand debugger stopped stepping into functions **properly**.

It works partially but with annoying caveats.
The debugger is stopping on breakpoints and step-over is working fine, but when I step into a function:

1. the debugger jumps to the definition of the function (as it should)
2. then when I press either step into/over, debugger just behaves as if I presses the continue button (F9) button and stops debugging.

I tried specifying a custom delve installation and it did not help. This happens on all types for code from hello world to unit test to gRPC service. Using GUI keys instead of keyboard shortcuts made no difference.

Anyone have an idea?

EDIT:

GoLand version 2022.3.2, Go 1.17/1.18 running on MacOS 13.2.

Comment: What version of GoLand and Go are you running and on what OS? Have you tried clicking the button rather than using F7 (key can be remapped)? You say "step-over is working" but then say "press F7 or F8.." (F8 is stepover so its unclear if that is working or not?). Have you tested with a simple "hello world" type program?

Comment: Please also try out the EAP version of GoLand: https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/. It bundles a new version of Delve so your case might be fixed.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem on my device. Goland 2022.3.2, Mac 13.2.1